# https API error

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

I can't get data by https.Track: h_ttp://soundcloud.com/celticwoman-1/a-womans-heart
If I use this request h_ttps://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=
h_ttps://soundcloud.com/celticwoman-1/a-womans-heart&format=json&consumer_key=my_key&callback=?
- all good, but this https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=
https://snd.sc/yMgQRJ&format=json&consumer_key=my_key&callback=? - error
404. I can't use first request because user already post player. You can
see this error here: https://www.facebook.com/celticwoman. If use http -
all ok.
Thanks.

Comment: Please format your question first :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the short form of the SoundCloud url that you have used, `snd.sc/yMgQRJ` does not support HTTPS - try `https://snd.sc/yMgQRJ` in your browser if you don't believe me.

Instead, change that to be `http://snd.sc/yMgQRJ`, which [worked for me](https://snap.apigee.com/GLWRaz) in the [API Console](http://developers.soundcloud.com/console).

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand how the player was a shortened url. When I received data I use property permalink_url for player. Sometimes In permalink_url used short url?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I haven't had any experience with the SoundCloud API, sorry. I just checked out the documentation on their site and played around with stuff to see if I could figure out the problem anyway.